# KMM - Build iOS application: failed with code 65

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I started my first [KMM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform.html) project, and after simply creating a KMM project in Android studio

I'm facing the following error:

```
Build iOS application: failed with code 65
```

Anybody has any insights?

**The error log is super long:**

```
  Command line invocation:
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/iosApp.xcworkspace -scheme iosApp -configuration Debug OBJROOT=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios SYMROOT=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios -sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64 -allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration -allowProvisioningUpdates
    
    User defaults from command line:
        IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
    
    Build settings from command line:
        ARCHS = x86_64
        OBJROOT = /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator15.2
        SYMROOT = /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
    
    2023-03-22 11:17:53.814 xcodebuild[4347:101876] CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer implemented and should not be called
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B00D440E-E4D8-4E78-8B2A-C19A402AA196, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0649EED2-807A-4420-8C51-8089D4FFEBBA, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:16B62A8E-70A5-4AC1-81FD-426786A4BBCE, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EA7A0DA7-A431-40A0-8502-2D6C1A2A9D87, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FAC4492F-C9A9-47B8-A37B-11FC0710F994, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1EC4744A-BE42-4EFF-8E82-A7A22B573E28, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7C8943BD-E313-4751-B324-33EA36E8946C, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:524A3599-AFC1-454B-8813-2B22D7E17724, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F10D2F91-0770-43A5-968C-893314A69C71, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CAE6B8ED-B80F-413E-99D8-45B903D39B55, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:84A548D8-1A53-4310-9E7D-0A9CCB082F0F, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FE162C89-4A47-48AB-86CF-764586EFE0C4, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E271F57C-FA1E-4C03-A212-4F2DCDFE67F5, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:AD9758E8-1E1B-4E0D-87DB-DCF3400BCB25, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:30985C01-769C-43EE-AA8B-1DA1FFE3630D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:39E1AF8C-E4AA-42B5-A9A2-1FBCDCBD6E4E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E11867F4-B0C9-4144-B31C-738975F0F79C, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:ABB6408A-3574-4132-B245-7D62CB71133E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4905A488-7720-4EE2-8BB5-BAF28FC253DB, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BF5A3633-5D3A-479B-9F9C-82ECA5F2EAFF, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:96004033-FF29-4102-B3F6-D3D20D848E99, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    Analyze workspace
    
    Create build description
    Build description signature: a72984972faea0b43babc3ae2d2ceccb
    Build description path: /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/XCBuildData/a72984972faea0b43babc3ae2d2ceccb-desc.xcbuild
    
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\ shared /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-BEA8885189D408D600647BDC228A6A20.sh (in target 'shared' from project 'Pods')
        cd /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods
        export ACTION\=build
        export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED\=YES
        export ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION\=NO
        export ALTERNATE_GROUP\=staff
        export ALTERNATE_MODE\=u+w,go-w,a+rX
        export ALTERNATE_OWNER\=myproject
        export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES\=NO
        export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS\=NO
        export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS\=NO
        export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Developer
        export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR\=/AppleInternal
        export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Documentation
        export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Library
        export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS\=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
        export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY\=NO
        export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES\=NO
        export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS\=NO
        export ARCHS\=x86_64
        export ARCHS_STANDARD\=arm64\ x86_64
        export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
        export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT\=i386
        export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64
        export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64
        export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
        export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME\=AppIcon
        export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GLOBAL_ACCENT_COLOR_NAME\=AccentColor
        export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS\=appletvos\ appletvsimulator\ driverkit\ iphoneos\ iphonesimulator\ macosx\ watchos\ watchsimulator
        export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE\=marker
        export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY\=YES
        export BUILD_COMPONENTS\=headers\ build
        export BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION\=NO
        export BUILD_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export BUILD_STYLE\=
        export BUILD_VARIANTS\=normal
        export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared
        export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep\=Contents/
        export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep\=MacOS
        export BUNDLE_FORMAT\=shallow
        export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH\=Frameworks
        export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH\=PlugIns
        export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=PrivateHeaders
        export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=Headers
        export CACHE_ROOT\=/var/folders/kz/q7ts21b92xd5xvxp_qnkj1cr0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/13.2.1-13C100/Xcode
        export CCHROOT\=/var/folders/kz/q7ts21b92xd5xvxp_qnkj1cr0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/13.2.1-13C100/Xcode
        export CHMOD\=/bin/chmod
        export CHOWN\=/usr/sbin/chown
        export CLANG_ANALYZER_LOCALIZABILITY_NONLOCALIZED\=YES
        export CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL\=YES
        export CLANG_ANALYZER_NUMBER_OBJECT_CONVERSION\=YES_AGGRESSIVE
        export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD\=gnu++14
        export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY\=libc++
        export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES\=YES
        export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC\=YES
        export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_WEAK\=NO
        export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE\=/Users/myproject/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
        export CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_COMMA\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE\=YES_ERROR
        export CLANG_WARN_DOCUMENTATION_COMMENTS\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS\=YES_ERROR
        export CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER\=NO
        export CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN_UNGUARDED_AVAILABILITY\=YES_AGGRESSIVE
        export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE\=YES
        export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH\=YES
        export CLASS_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/JavaClasses
        export CLEAN_PRECOMPS\=YES
        export CLONE_HEADERS\=NO
        export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared/
        export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED\=NO
        export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED\=YES
        export CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS\=XCiPhoneSimulatorCodeSignContext
        export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY\=-
        export CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS\=YES
        export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS\=NO
        export COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES\=NO
        export COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE\=Default
        export COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/CompositeSDKs
        export COMPRESS_PNG_FILES\=YES
        export CONFIGURATION\=Debug
        export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared
        export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
        export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA\=NO
        export COPY_HEADERS_RUN_UNIFDEF\=NO
        export COPY_PHASE_STRIP\=NO
        export COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS\=YES
        export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
        export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\=iphoneos
        export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.2.sdk
        export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_NAME\=iphoneos15.2
        export CP\=/bin/cp
        export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY\=NO
        export CURRENT_ARCH\=undefined_arch
        export CURRENT_VARIANT\=normal
        export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING\=YES
        export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS\=YES
        export DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT\=dwarf
        export DEFAULT_COMPILER\=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
        export DEFAULT_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
        export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/Extensions
        export DEFINES_MODULE\=NO
        export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION\=NO
        export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING\=NO
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME\=mios-simulator-version-min
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_PREFIX\=-mios-simulator-version-min\=
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_ENV_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_FLAG_NAME\=ios_simulator_version_min
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
        export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SUGGESTED_VALUES\=9.0\ 9.1\ 9.2\ 9.3\ 10.0\ 10.1\ 10.2\ 10.3\ 11.0\ 11.1\ 11.2\ 11.3\ 11.4\ 12.0\ 12.1\ 12.2\ 12.3\ 12.4\ 13.0\ 13.1\ 13.2\ 13.3\ 13.4\ 13.5\ 13.6\ 14.0\ 14.1\ 14.2\ 14.3\ 14.4\ 14.5\ 14.6\ 14.7\ 15.0\ 15.1\ 15.2
        export DERIVED_FILES_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/DerivedSources
        export DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/DerivedSources
        export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/DerivedSources
        export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
        export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
        export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
        export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
        export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
        export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
        export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
        export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
        export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE\=en
        export DONT_GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE\=NO
        export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM\=NO
        export DSTROOT\=/tmp/Pods.dst
        export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
        export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME\=.dSYM
        export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT\=NO
FILE_LIST\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Objects/LinkFileList
        export OBJECT_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Objects
   PLATFORM_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
        export PLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME\=iOS\ Simulator
        export PLATFORM_FAMILY_NAME\=iOS
        export PLATFORM_NAME\=iphonesimulator
        export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH\=x86_64
        export PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=19C51
        export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT\=binary
        export PODS_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator
        export PODS_DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE\=en
        export PODS_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods
        export PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods/../../shared
        export PODS_XCFRAMEWORKS_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates
        export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR\=YES
        export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/PrefixHeaders
        export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS\=NO
        export PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER\=org.cocoapods.shared
        export PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME\=shared
        export PRODUCT_NAME\=shared
        export PRODUCT_SETTINGS_PATH\=
        export PROFILING_CODE\=NO
        export PROJECT\=Pods
        export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/DerivedSources
        export PROJECT_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods
        export PROJECT_FILE_PATH\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj
        export PROJECT_NAME\=Pods
        export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build
        export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATHS_FOLLOW_SYMLImyproject\=YES
        export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES\=YES
        export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES\=YES
        export REZ_COLLECTOR_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/ResourceManagerResources
        export REZ_OBJECTS_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects
        export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES\=NO
        export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_INPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_COUNT\=0
        export SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_LIST_COUNT\=0
        export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk
        export SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk
        export SDK_DIR_iphonesimulator\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk
        export SDK_DIR_iphonesimulator15_2\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk
        export SDK_NAME\=iphonesimulator15.2
        export SDK_NAMES\=iphonesimulator15.2
        export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=19C51
        export SDK_VERSION\=15.2
        export SDK_VERSION_ACTUAL\=150200
        export SDK_VERSION_MAJOR\=150000
        export SDK_VERSION_MINOR\=150200
        export SED\=/usr/bin/sed
        export SEPARATE_STRIP\=NO
        export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT\=NO
        export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=YES
        export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=NO
        export SHALLOW_BUNDLE\=NO
        export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared/DerivedSources
        export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR\=/Users/myproject/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-cdidbsdgvcbwvxcpliegoieonfin/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders
        export SKIP_INSTALL\=YES
        export SOURCE_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods
        export SRCROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/iosApp/Pods
        export STRINGSDATA_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Objects-normal/undefined_arch
        export STRINGSDATA_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build
        export STRINGS_FILE_INFOPLIST_RENAME\=YES
        export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING\=binary
        export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES\=NO
        export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT\=NO
        export STRIP_STYLE\=all
        export STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS\=YES
        export SUPPORTED_DEVICE_FAMILIES\=1,2
        export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS\=iphoneos\ iphonesimulator
        export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API\=NO
        export SWIFT_ACTIVE_COMPILATION_CONDITIONS\=DEBUG
        export SWIFT_EMIT_LOC_STRINGS\=NO
        export SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL\=-Onone
        export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX\=ios
        export SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE_PATH_normal_x86_64\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/shared.SwiftFileList
        export SWIFT_VERSION\=5.0
        export SYMROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Utilities
        export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR\=/Applications
        export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR\=/System/Library/CoreServices
        export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR\=/Applications/Extras
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built\ Examples
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance\ Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/documentation/DeveloperTools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC\ Reference\ Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
        export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
        export SYSTEM_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
        export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/Library/Documentation
        export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/Extensions
        export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR\=/System/Library
        export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE\=ErrorsOnly
        export TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY\=1,2
        export TARGETNAME\=shared
        export TARGET_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared
        export TARGET_DEVICE_IDENTIFIER\=dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder
        export TARGET_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\=iphonesimulator
        export TARGET_NAME\=shared
        export TARGET_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build
        export TEMP_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build
        export TEMP_FILES_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build
        export TEMP_FILE_DIR\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build
        export TEMP_ROOT\=/Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios
        export TEST_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS\=\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
        export TEST_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS\=\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib
        export TOOLCHAINS\=com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault
        export TOOLCHAIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
        export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES\=NO
        export UID\=501
        export UNSTRIPPED_PRODUCT\=NO
        export USER\=myproject
        export USER_APPS_DIR\=/Users/myproject/Applications
        export USER_LIBRARY_DIR\=/Users/myproject/Library
        export USE_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC\=YES
        export USE_HEADERMAP\=YES
        export USE_HEADER_SYMLImyproject\=NO
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD\=YES
        export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI\=YES
        export USE_RECURSIVE_SCRIPT_INPUTS_IN_SCRIPT_PHASES\=YES
        export VALIDATE_DEVELOPMENT_ASSET_PATHS\=YES_ERROR
        export VALIDATE_PRODUCT\=NO
        export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE\=YES_ERROR
        export VALID_ARCHS\=arm64\ arm64e\ i386\ x86_64
        export VERBOSE_PBXCP\=NO
        export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER\=myproject
        export VERSION_INFO_FILE\=shared_vers.c
        export VERSION_INFO_STRING\=\"@\(\#\)PROGRAM:shared\ \ PROJECT:Pods-\"
        export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES\=NO
        export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
        export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=13C100
        export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL\=1321
        export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR\=1300
        export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR\=1320
        export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH\=/XPCServices
        export YACC\=yacc
        export arch\=undefined_arch
        export variant\=normal
        /bin/sh -c /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-BEA8885189D408D600647BDC228A6A20.sh
                    REPO_ROOT="$PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT"
                    "$REPO_ROOT/../gradlew" -p "$REPO_ROOT" $KOTLIN_PROJECT_PATH:syncFramework                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.platform=$PLATFORM_NAME                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.archs="$ARCHS"                     -Pkotlin.native.cocoapods.configuration="$CONFIGURATION"
    The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
    Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
    
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    
    ** BUILD FAILED **
    
    
    The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Build\ shared /Users/myproject/AndroidStudioProjects/Multi1/build/ios/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.build/Script-BEA8885189D408D600647BDC228A6A20.sh (in target 'shared' from project 'Pods')
    (1 failure)
```

Comment: Did you use KMM plugin to create project?

Comment: @iamanbansal Yes I do

Comment: Did you try running kdoctor? I think you're missing Java in ur system

Comment: @iamanbansal Hi, that was the problem, if you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running [KDoctor](https://github.com/Kotlin/kdoctor) on your system. KDoctor ensures that all required components are properly installed and ready for use.

As the error says, Java is missing in your system

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Comment: my kdoctor is fine and ios used to run yesterday but for some reason not today. nothing changed. i have no idea. same error 65